# Is there any security risk in having many foreign keys referencing a single table?

Tags: security, foreign-key, database-agnostic

I have a teacher who told me that having a database with a table that's referenced by around 60% of the other tables was a security no-no. The problem is that he failed to explain why it was a security risk.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the only one who knows why it might be a security risk is your teacher. I have never heard such a notion.

Comment: I would ask the teacher for clarification. As far as I know there wouldn't be an actual security risk, maybe performance issues as your indexes grow large (Incredibly large for there to be issues) But maybe he means a security risk in a not so literal way? Maybe a malicious user gaining access to the main table that is referenced and deleting records, and having the affects cascade to the rest?

Comment: Can't think of any security risks associated with such a design. You could argue it's a poor design if it's for an OLTP system but star schemas are very common and very effective for data marts and data warehouses. It serves specific workloads very well and has its drawbacks but they are primarily from performance perspective, not security. I'm guessing many here are curious to know what security risks your teacher has identified for this type of schema.

Answer (score 1):

This stretches the bounds of credibility.  The only thing I can think of is that by deliberately causing referential integrity errors the attacker is able to harvest the error messages and derive information the underlying schema.

However, if the attacker is able to do that you have bigger worries.

Answer (score 1):

What is a risk - of a kind - I believe, is that if you overlook the REFERENCES permission on an object when denying an account direct access to the object, REFERENCES can be used to read data that someone wasn't supposed to be able to read - from the referenced key column, at least.  And the key column might be a bank account number or an SSN.  At least, you could exploit it to find whether data value ABCDEF is or isn't in the table.  Oracle's documentation says "grant privileges conservatively", which means don't grant them at all, ideally deny them explicitly.  Especially keep them away from a 'public' or 'guest' account that doesn't specifically need to have a permission on your database.

On a high-standard server (I use Microsoft SQL Server) this may be mitigated where Table A is referenced by Table B, and also by Tables C to Z, -but- it's the other tables themselves that have the right to look up a foreign key in Table A, it isn't a right of the user.  Unless the user can update data in Table M, which allows them once again to probe the values of data held in Table A.

As for risks other than security...  Keys are put there to be referenced.  A good server shouldn't break down if one table is referenced by all the others, although in "I Wrote My Own SQL Server All In Javascript" (which I hope is imaginary) something could go wrong.  Certainly if one key column is being referenced heavily by relationships and queries, then its specification and its indexing must be considered carefully.  For instance, Microsoft SQL allows an index on columns A and B to operate as a separate copy of the table data, and to have columns C, D, and E included in the doppelganger table as well (the INCLUDE keyword).  And meanwhile another index is also on keys A and B with columns F and G included too.  If that represents the two queries that you make most often, that's a design to consider.

Also, from experience, if your much-referenced data key needs to be changed, in all the tables, while keeping the rest of the data the same, that's vastly inconvenient.  For instance if it's the customer's telephone number (say this is the telephone company database), then you have to change the customer's number after nuisance calls.  Well, this is a reason to not use that kind of number as a key throughout the database - even though it's so convenient to look up data in a query on table PDQOK using that handy value.  Or, worse, that customer quits - then, you issue their number to somebody else...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't give more context than what's already available, your teacher's wrong.

Such schemas are called star schemas or snowflake schemas in OLAP databases and are best practice and standard of choice there. You'd need something like `Sales number` in the central table though and you would have customers and other stuff in the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the teacher's definition of security risk.

[IT Risk Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT_risk_management) according to an article on Wikipedia has the following definition:

> According to Risk IT,[1] it encompasses not just only the negative impact of operations and service delivery which can bring destruction or reduction of the value of the organization, but also the benefit\value enabling risk **associated to missing opportunities to use technology to enable or enhance business or the IT project management for aspects like overspending or late delivery with adverse business impact.**

Following up on the article you come across the following formula:

> **Risk = Threat * Vulnerability * Asset**

Now you could carry on and define your table data as assets and a general risk as a security risk, because your assets contains sensitive data, which leaves you with:

> **Security Risk = Threat * Vulnerability * Table_Data**

So in a really far-fetched sense a **Threat** combined with a **Vulnerability** could lead to a breach of data in your **Table_Data**. And as a result you have a **Security Risk**.

Now having all the relevant data referenced in your central table could pose a heightened security risk from your teacher's perspective, but that is very far fetched.

---

**Basically anything can be defined as a security risk. It depends on your argumentation.**